# php code to send checkbox form results to email

Tags: php, email

Would really appreciate some help for a php novice!

HTML form has the following checkbox list:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="servicetype[]" value="Option A"> Option A<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="servicetype[]" value="Option B"> Option B<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="servicetype[]" value="Option C"> Option C<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="servicetype[]" value="Option D"> Option D<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="servicetype[]" value="Option E"> Option E<br>
```

The php code below is not working though. I want the ticked options on the form to be sent in the email. All other non checkbox date arrives ok. Here is the php:

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->to = "my@emailadddress.com";            
$mail->from  =   $_REQUEST["emailaddress"];
$mail->subject = "Form Results";
$mail->body.= "Name: ".$_REQUEST["title"]." ".$_REQUEST["firstname"]." ".$_REQUEST["surname"]. "\n";
$mail->body.= "Email Address: ".$_REQUEST["emailaddress"]. "\n";            
$mail->body.= "Phone Number: ".$_REQUEST["telephonenumber"]. "\n";
$mail->body.= "Address:  ".$_REQUEST["addressline1"]. "\n";    
$mail->body.= $_REQUEST["addressline2"]. "\n";                
$mail->body.= "Town/City:  ".$_REQUEST["towncity"]. "\n";
$mail->body.= "County/State:  ".$_REQUEST["countystate"]. "\n";            
$mail->body.= "Post Code: ".$_REQUEST["postcode"]."\n";
$mail->body.= "Country: ".$_REQUEST["country"]."\n";            

$servicetype = $_POST['servicetype'];
$body .= "servicetype: \r\n".

foreach ($servicetype as $selected) {
$body .= " > ".$selected."\r\n";      
}


$mail->send();
$success=1;
```

The servicetype bit in the php is the part I have copied in without success. Can anyone pls help?

Comment: Just a note: your script is vulnerable as you’re just passing request data directly to it without first sanitizing the data. If a malicious user sends some nasty data to your script, then your script will just act on it blindly.

Comment: What do you mean "without success"?   What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1):

- You store the service type related texts in `$body` instead of `$mail->body`, ie it will not get included into your mail.
- You also ended a line with a `.` instead of a `;`
- You suddenly start using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. This should not matter (assuming you use the `post` method in your form), but it is 'odd' and error-prone to suddenly switch between the two.
- You need to check if a cehckbox actually got selected, otherwise `$servicetype` will be unset and you get errors. Use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for this check.

So, change the last part of your code into:

```
$servicetype = $_POST['servicetype'];
if(isset($servicetype)) {
    $mail->body .= "servicetype: \r\n";

    foreach ($servicetype as $selected) {
        $mail->body .= " > ".$selected."\r\n";      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response! However on testing the php script it works fine as long as at least one option is chosen. If NO option is chosen, then a php error appears.... any ideas pls?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this-

```
$servicetype = implode(",", $_POST['servicetype']);
$mail->body .= $servicetype."\r\n";
```